# installing Canon LBP 6230dn network printer on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: printing

I am very new to Linux world, last one week trying to install Canon LBP 6230dn printer in Ubuntu. Please guide me the step by step installation procedure for Canon LBP 6230dn network printer on Ubuntu 14.04

Comment: can you link where the driver is, what steps have you tried?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

Download the driver:

[LBP 6230 Linux](http://gdlp01.c-wss.com/gds/0/0100005950/03/Linux_UFRIILT_PrinterDriver_V120_uk_EN.tar.gz)

Open a terminal,

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>

Run it:

```
cd /home/user/Downloads
tar zxf Linux_UFRIILT_PrinterDriver_V120_uk_EN.tar.gz
cd /home/user/Downloads/Linux_UFRIILT_PrinterDriver_V120_uk_EN
sudo ./install.sh
```

Answer (score 0):

Linux Driver download Link https://asia.canon/en/support/0100595001?model=9143B004

Then Open a terminal,

Press Ctrl+Alt+T

Run it:

cd /home/user/Downloads
tar zxf ./linux-UFRIILT-drv-v500-uken-18.tar.gz
cd /home/user/Downloads/linux-UFRIILT-drv-v500-uken
sudo ./install.sh