# Unable to print from canon lbp 6230DN printer on 16.10 and issues with installation of the drivers

Tags: networking, printing, 16.10, canon, additional-drivers

I am trying to install Canon LBP 6230dn network pritner on ubuntu 16.10 using the method suggeted on the page: [installing Canon LBP 6230dn network printer on Ubuntu 14.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/711584/installing-canon-lbp-6230dn-network-printer-on-ubuntu-14-04)

I am getting the following error messages. Please help.

```
*This installer is recommended for Fedora or Ubuntu distributions that are currently supported as of the release of this installer.
If this installer is run under earlier or later distributions, the installation of additional system libraries may be necessary after driver installation is complete.
Do you want to continue with installation? (y/n) y
#----------------------------------------------------#
# Install Start
#----------------------------------------------------#
Machine Type = x86_64
Package Type = rpm
Package list = 
    ./64-bit_Driver/RPM/cndrvcups-common-3.30-1.x86_64.rpm
    ./64-bit_Driver/RPM/cndrvcups-ufr2lt-uk-1.20-1.x86_64.rpm
#----------------------------------------------------#
# dnf upgrade
#----------------------------------------------------#
pangox-compat
./install.sh: line 196: dnf: command not found
libxml2
./install.sh: line 196: dnf: command not found
libxml2.i686
./install.sh: line 196: dnf: command not found
glibc
./install.sh: line 196: dnf: command not found
glibc.i686
./install.sh: line 196: dnf: command not found
libstdc++
./install.sh: line 196: dnf: command not found
libstdc++.i686
./install.sh: line 196: dnf: command not found
libjpeg-turbo
./install.sh: line 196: dnf: command not found
libjpeg-turbo.i686
./install.sh: line 196: dnf: command not found
beecrypt.i686
./install.sh: line 196: dnf: command not found
beecrypt-devel.i686
./install.sh: line 196: dnf: command not found
#----------------------------------------------------#
# dnf install
#----------------------------------------------------#
./install.sh: line 204: dnf: command not found
#----------------------------------------------------#
# Install Package Check
#----------------------------------------------------#
 NG: pangox-compat
 NG: libxml2
 NG: libxml2.i686
 NG: glibc
 NG: glibc.i686
 NG: libstdc++
 NG: libstdc++.i686
 NG: libjpeg-turbo
 NG: libjpeg-turbo.i686
 NG: beecrypt.i686
 NG: beecrypt-devel.i686
Some system libraries could not be installed.
Refer to the online manual for more information.
Do you want to continue with installation? (y/n)*
```